# mean.io what's the best way to set up an admin user + admin module

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

All the times I use http://www.mean.io/
I've got the hassle to set up an admin user + admin module
+ (if needs) manage acl

What I do up to now:

**add this rule tomodels/user.js**

```
role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: 'authoring'
}
```

**set up an init.js for sign up
the user admin like:**

```
var userData = { "name" : "User Admin", "email" : "info@mydomain.com", "username" : "admin","role" : "admin","password":"admin"};
var user = new User(userData);
user.provider = 'local';
user.save(function(err) {  
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit();
        return;
    }
    console.log(user); 
    process.exit();
});
```

**set up three folders**

- admin
- default
- login

I don't trust manage sensible data
only client side

**set up acl**

**a simple acl both for the server and for 
the client like:**

```
//SERVER
'use strict';

/**
 * Generic require login routing middleware
 */
exports.requiresLogin = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect('/signin');
    }
    next();
};

/**
 * Generic require login routing middleware
 */
exports.apiRequiresLogin = function(req, res,next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.jsonp(401,{ error:'User is not authorized'});
    }
    next();
};

// Profile authorization helpers
exports.isOwnerProfile = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user.role !== 'admin') {
        if (req.profile.id !== req.user.id) {
            return res.send(401, 'User is not authorized');
        }
    }
    next();
};

// User admin authorization helpers
exports.isAdmin = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user.role !== 'admin') {
        return res.send(401, 'User is not authorized');
    }
    next();
};

// Article authorization helpers
exports.requireSameAuthor = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.post.user.id !== req.user.id) {
        return res.send(401, 'User is not authorized');
    }
    next();
};
//CLIENT
.factory('Global', function($cookieStore) {
        var user = $cookieStore.get('USER');
        var _this = this;
        _this._data = {
            user: user,
            _authenticated: !!user,
            _isAdmin: (user.role==='admin'),
            isAuthenticated: function() {
                return this._authenticated;
            },
            isAdmin: function() {
                return this._isAdmin;
            },
            isActionDisabled:function(post){
                if(this.isAdmin()){
                    return false;
                }
                return (this.user.id === post.author_id);
            }
        };
        return _this._data;
    })
```

What's the best way to set up a admin user + admin module + acl ?

I saw in the new realise there are packages 
can them be usefull for this ?

### UPDATE

Sorry I didn't see the doc
http://www.mean.io/#!/docs

Answer (score 5):

Yes the mean packages are what you will want to use. To install mean:

```
npm install -g meanio
```

To install the mean-admin package:

```
mean install mean-admin
```

To create admin role for user:

```
mean user <your_signin_email> -a admin
```

Comment: am getting some error while using mean user <your_signin_email> -a admin

Comment: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/cli.js:1119
      if (err) throw new Error(err);
                     ^
Error: Error: Cannot find module '/Users/JineshJohn/Desktop/SOA/server/config/env/development.js'
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/cli.js:1119:22
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/cli.js:111:21
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/utils.js:49:14
    at fs.js:272:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)

Comment: The functions of the mean-cli are very dependent on the folder structure of your project. When you run 'mean user <your_signin_email> -a admin' the mean-cli is looking for a mongo database to connect to (that's how it marks you as admin for the website) and its looking for the connection string a file located in '/Users/JineshJohn/Desktop/SOA/server/config/env/' called 'development.js'.  This is how mean configures the mean server when you first install with 'mean init myApp'. If you have changed the folder structure a lot then many features of mean will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just so others have the info in the docs...
You can add a rool through the command..
mean user (email) -a admin